# What is the precedence of constraint violations in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

Database systems reject operation that violate entity integrity constraint, referential integrity constraint, etc. There are also constraints enforced via assertions/triggers. Is there any precedence in the order of detection of violations or are both violations detected alltogether?

Comment: In practice, the constraints are processed sequentially.  The exact order might depend on the database -- and might not even be documented.

Comment: What's the use case? I haven't faced any case where I need to actually know which one is validated first.

Comment: I agree with The Impaler - what is the point?  A violation is a violation.  I am curious as to why this is significant for you.